# PyMC3 Implementation of Probabilistic Matrix Factorization (PMF): MAP produces all 0s

Tags: probability, bayesian, python, pymc, probabilistic-programming

I've started working with pymc3 over the past few days, and after getting a feel for the basics, I've tried implementing the [Probabilistic Matrix Factorization](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3208-probabilistic-matrix-factorization.pdf) model.

For validation, I use a subset of the Jester dataset. I take the first 100 users who rated all 100 jokes. I use the first 20 jokes and leave the ratings unchanged; they are in the range [-10, 10] for all jokes. For ease of reference, I've made this subset available [here](https://gist.github.com/macks22/b40ac9c685e920ad3ca2#file-jester-dense-subset-100x20).

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import theano

data = pd.read_csv('jester-dense-subset-100x20.csv')    
n, m = data.shape
test_size = m / 10
train_size = m - test_size

train = data.copy()
train.ix[:,train_size:] = np.nan  # remove test set data
train[train.isnull()] = train.mean().mean()  # mean value imputation
train = train.values

test = data.copy()
test.ix[:,:train_size] = np.nan  # remove train set data
test = test.values    

# Low precision reflects uncertainty; prevents overfitting
alpha_u = alpha_v = 1/np.var(train)
alpha = np.ones((n,m)) * 2  # fixed precision for likelihood function
dim = 10  # dimensionality

# Specify the model.
with pm.Model() as pmf:
    pmf_U = pm.MvNormal('U', mu=0, tau=alpha_u * np.eye(dim),
                        shape=(n, dim))
    pmf_V = pm.MvNormal('V', mu=0, tau=alpha_v * np.eye(dim),
                        shape=(m, dim))
    pmf_R = pm.Normal('R', mu=theano.tensor.dot(pmf_U, pmf_V.T),
                      tau=alpha, observed=train)

    # Find mode of posterior using optimization
    start = pm.find_MAP()  # Find starting values by optimization
```

This all appears to work splendidly, but the values produced by `find_MAP` end up being all 0s for both U and V, as can be seen by running:

```
(start['U'] == 0).all()
(start['V'] == 0).all()
```

I am relatively new to both Bayesian modeling and pymc, so I could easily be missing something obvious here. Why am I getting all 0s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did two things to fix your code. One was to initialize the model away from zero, the other one was to use a non-gradient based optimizer:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import theano
import scipy as sp

data = pd.read_csv('jester-dense-subset-100x20.csv')    
n, m = data.shape
test_size = m / 10
train_size = m - test_size

train = data.copy()
train.ix[:,train_size:] = np.nan  # remove test set data
train[train.isnull()] = train.mean().mean()  # mean value imputation
train = train.values

test = data.copy()
test.ix[:,:train_size] = np.nan  # remove train set data
test = test.values    

# Low precision reflects uncertainty; prevents overfitting
alpha_u = alpha_v = 1/np.var(train)
alpha = np.ones((n,m)) * 2  # fixed precision for likelihood function
dim = 10  # dimensionality

# Specify the model.
with pm.Model() as pmf:
    pmf_U = pm.MvNormal('U', mu=0, tau=alpha_u * np.eye(dim),
                        shape=(n, dim), testval=np.random.randn(n, dim)*.01)
    pmf_V = pm.MvNormal('V', mu=0, tau=alpha_v * np.eye(dim),
                        shape=(m, dim), testval=np.random.randn(m, dim)*.01)
    pmf_R = pm.Normal('R', mu=theano.tensor.dot(pmf_U, pmf_V.T),
                      tau=alpha, observed=train)

    # Find mode of posterior using optimization
    start = pm.find_MAP(fmin=sp.optimize.fmin_powell)  # Find starting values by optimization

    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)
    trace = pm.sample(500, step, start=start)
```

This is an interesting model that would make a great contribution. Please consider adding this, once you're certain it works as desired, to the examples folder and do a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes! Do you mind commenting on why these changes are necessary to avoid the 0-valued start matrices?

Comment: Does it produce sensible results that way?

Unfortunately I don't have a good explanation. I kind of intuited that starting at 0 would be a very odd space in the likelihood with an ill-defined gradient (I'm not sure if that's actually the case). This still didn't work with the gradient based optimization so I tried Powell which usually is pretty robust. You could try still starting at 0 with Powell which might be good enough.

Comment: Just going off of RMSE, it seems the MAP estimate is reasonable. The test RMSE for 5.0823, which is slightly better than what comes out from using a simple baseline. If I just replace all missing values by the global mean, the test RMSE is 5.0839. The best I can produce with [libFM](http://www.libfm.org/) is 4.980.

Comment: Note that the 4.980 number mentioned above was incorporating  bias terms, both global and per-item/per-joke. That model was also using 8 dimensions. If I leave out the bias terms and use 10 dimensions, as I do for the PMF model, then the test RMSE is around 5.2 using libFM. This model is similar to a regularized SVD, which PMF is supposed to improve upon.

Comment: Following the advice of [Salakhutdinov and Mnih, p.886](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~amnih/papers/bpmf.pdf), I also monitored the Frobenius norms of the sampled U and V matrices. They converge after 7-10 samples, which I believe is quite rapid. This also leads me to believe the MAP estimate is reasonable. Interestingly, the MAP estimate actually produces a better RMSE than the sampler, which gives a test RMSE of 5.108 using 400 samples, after discarding 10 samples as burn-in.

Comment: That's great, glad it's working! If you have a nice plot to go with this, would you consider making a pull request for pymc3 to add this to the examples folder? We're currently missing multivariate examples. Even better (but optional) would be a short description/intuition of the model. IPython NB would be best as it could be easily added to the docs.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. The `traceplot` function isn't much use for high-dimensional sampling spaces. So I'm planning to produce plots of RMSE and perhaps model perplexity as a function of sample number. I'll also include a plot of the norms, which provides a visual cue for sampler convergence.